# Interview form with angularjs (repeat and model)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I want to make interview questions form with ng-repeat, where when i click submit, it will send all the data, so i need different ng-model for that.

Here is my code

```
<form role="form" name="interviewForm">
  <div class="pr_setportfolio_content interview_div" ng-show="setinterview == true">
       <div class="prterms_name_input" ng-repeat="interview in interview">
           <span class="prterms_input_text">
             {{interview.question}}
           </span>
           <textarea class="prterms_inputtextarea_name" ng-model="interview_answer" name="interview_answer" placeholder="Enter answer" msd-elastic auto-resize></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So, anyone have any idea how to make it?

Thank you

Comment: try use `ng-model="interview.interview_answer"`

Comment: I think [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YoG80AR0RiZJKs8OZVYU?p=preview) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same model (for example `interview.answer` instead of `interview_answer`) for holding answers and then you can get answer for each question in same model. Just iterate on `interview` list and each index will hold one question and its answer

```
<form role="form" name="interviewForm">
<div class="pr_setportfolio_content interview_div" ng-show="setinterview == true">
  <div class="prterms_name_input" ng-repeat="interview in interview">
    <span class="prterms_input_text">
      {{interview.question}}
    </span>
    <textarea class="prterms_inputtextarea_name" ng-model="interview.answer" name="interview_answer" placeholder="Enter answer" msd-elastic auto-resize></textarea>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
ng-repeat="intview in interview"

<textarea class="prterms_inputtextarea_name" data-ng-model="intview.interview_answer" name="interview_answer" placeholder="Enter answer" msd-elastic auto-resize></textarea>
```

After submitting this form, just collect the answer `interview.interview_answer` is not null or undefined.